# Account dropdown menu on mobile is not showing when logged in

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, responsive-design, dropdown

It works fine on desktop Site URL https://www.coastdailydeals.net

After logged in on mobil, top right click the button Greg two and a dropdown should show with my account, my favorite deals and sign out buttons.

Been working on it for hours can't figure out why.

Comment: The problem is that because of the `slideToggle` effect, the `.topLinks` get `overflow:hidden`. So, the `.sectionDown.dropWrap` hidden because it out of the `.topLinks`. You need figure it out how to remove the `overflow:hidden` once the menu is open.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't post usernames and passwords in public places.  If you need to make something public, you should use something like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or a temporary sub site without the need of login to show something public.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When looking for help here, it is best to create a [mcve] that reproduces your problem. People here usually don't want to visit your site to see the problem. By showing the relevant code here, you make it easier for people to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Tat fixed it. Thanks. And thanks for the tip